# PostgreSQL database data not showing on DSpace repository after rebuilding

Tags: postgresql, dspace

Recently migrated from a DSpace 5.5 installation to DSpace 6.2. Successfully restored the database from a PostgreSQL DB dump and have no issues with the database connection, DSpace installation and building, however, no data (i.e. Communities and Records) display on the site. Worked well once before but after executing a number of xmlui changes no data. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I am surprised that you cannot see Communities or Collections.  Try running index-discovery and see if that makes the items visible: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Discovery

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked after this.

Answer (score 1):

Database migrate commands need to be run after upgrade. Indexing also needs to be run.

```
/dspace/bin/dspace filter-media

/dspace/bin/dspace index-discovery
```

Communities are now getting pulled from the database. The process, however, takes time to run.